# Relative URLs when working on localhost

Tags: php, html, url, localhost

Since now I've had a habit - working directly on live domains or subdomains. Now I've discovered the charm and speed with working on localhost. I am using a Wamp server on Windows machine.

My project is stored in C:/wamp64/www/[project_name]

I've been using relative URLs since forever, either in source files or directly in my WordPress sites. For example, using this URL for image: "/wp-content/uploads/2018/image.png" worked on every domain, same goes for pages or articles.

However on localhost this URL points to C:/wamp64/www/wp-content/..., so I have to use this URL: "/project_name/wp-content/...". However, it does not work after migration to a live domain.

I tried to run SQL REPLACE queries, but there are still plenty of URLs that are pointing to local dirs (mainly those stored in the theme settings).

**What is the best approach to work with relative URLs, that would work on both localhost server, and live domain?**

Comment: I prefer using `<base>` tag for entire project. You just need to update base when migrating to the server.

Comment: Just change the docroot for your local WP VirtualHost (httpd-vhosts.conf) so that the relative directory structure is the same both locally and live, then you can continue to use URLs that begin with **/** and everything's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like there is an issue with your virtual host settings in WAMP.

[Guide to setup virtual host](https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/)

Once you setup your virtual host, you can set your document root to be any URL you want. This will allow you to use a specific name for your local (i.e. kritianfilo.local) instead of using the full path each time. This will also fix the issue regarding relative URLs, as everything will be relative to the document root you set in your virtual host settings

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! I'm new to this, sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize, this is how we all learn!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use relative paths but in this way: "../wp-content/uploads/2018/image.png"

Don't begin the relative paths with "/" because it means that your site will be on top of the path: "http://Examlple.com". As Wordpress can be installed in subpaths it dont work in "http://Example.com/OtherSite/".

So think always relative to the actual page and not to the top page.

Answer (score 0):

one approach is to create a config or sys properties file which holds all system related variables and is queried by your application whenever needed.

In your localhost environment, you can insert the WAMP/Windows absolute path and in your dev/prod environment, you can use the relative paths (or absolute as well).

Works fine, but you have to remember to set the right values with each deployment.